# Converting string_id to number_id

Tags: neural-network, data-cleaning

I have column with movie ids like this:

```
tt0984332
tt0984332
tt0847742
ttnanana1
```

I would like to convert them into numbers that can be inserted into neural network as features, like this:

```
0
0
1
2
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What is the information contained in those strings ?

Comment: string contains id of a movie

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is performed exactly by `sklearn.LabelEncoder`, an example of which can be found [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html).

In your case:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(["tt0984332", "tt0984332", "tt0847742", "ttnanana1"])

# Show the unique classes
print(encoder.classes_)
# out: array(['tt0847742', 'tt0984332', 'ttnanana1'], dtype='<U9')

# Convert labels to integers
encoder.transform(["tt0984332", "tt0984332", "tt0847742", "ttnanana1"])
# out: array([1, 1, 0, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#I did just index mapping using dictionary and then added it to data frame
#preprocess itemid
unique_items = set(df.itemid.values)
item_to_idx_dict = {}
item_count = 0

for item in unique_items:
    item_to_idx_dict[item] = item_count
    item_count += 1

df['item_idx'] = df.apply(lambda row: item_to_idx_dict[row.itemid], axis = 1)
```